# The Screen moves to right when TextView data exceeds its size

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I have a UI in which I show details of the customers. Now some customer address are long and when I display it in the TextView the full screen layout shifts in the direction of the end of the address Textview and hence some of the parameters get hidden. How can i keep the length of the address textview fix. I tried something like this with ellipsize but no luck.

```
    <style name="CustomerTextView">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/textview_border</item>
  <item name ="android:ellipsize">end</item>  
  </style>
```

and my XML file for the customer address looks like this

```
 <TableRow android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/customerAddress" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="right" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customerAddress"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right" />

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: i would like to but how can i attach screenshot here

Comment: when you click on edit there is an option to add image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:maxEms`, `android:maxLength` or `android:maxWidth`  in your layout to control the width of your `TextView`. You can also use `android:maxLines` to control the number of lines your `TextView` will take. I have added the maxEms line to your TextView declaration.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customerAddress"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:maxEms="25"
            android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: i need to use this in my stype or in the xml file

Comment: You can add these as your TextView properties in the XML Layout file. I'd prefer using maxEms over the other two. Just experiment with different values until you find one that works.

Comment: I added this to my style file and it worked.Is it alright to use width or no
    <item name ="android:width">15dp</item>

Comment: No, in your textView named customerAddress

Comment: If it worked for you, it's fine. But using maxWidth is not a good idea since it uses pixels which will change from screen to screen. Use maxEms instead.

Comment: can you please give me an e.g. of this maxEms and by the way I added dp,so it will not use pixel and use dp instead which is recommended by android.correct??