# TextView does not show all the text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Ui which shows customer information. The problem I have is some customer name(android:id="@+id/customerName") is long and does not fit in the textview. what option i ahev to beable to display them other then the option to give full layout width to the name or removing the code textview from next to it(as seen in the xml file android:id="@+id/customerName").

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/customerCode" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/customerName" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customerCode"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customerName"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxEms="5"  />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/customerAddress" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customerAddress"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxEms="5"   
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/POBox" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/OrganizationName" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poBox"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/organizationName"
            style="@style/CustomerTextView"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/fax" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/CustomerLabelTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/phone" />
    </TableRow>
```

====================================STYLE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<style name="CustomerTextView">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/textview_border</item>
```

Comment: What about  android:lines="4" attribute

Comment: I tried this but does not work
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerName"
                style="@style/CustomerTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:maxEms="5"
                android:lines="4"   />

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it by using

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make it ellipsize, so if a name is 'Really Long Name", it might show up as "Really Lon...". To do this:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

On the other hand, you can make the textview change size to fit the text using:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

But I'm not sure if it'll work with everything else you're trying to do (eg fill_parent and width inside a tablerow)

Comment: i tried android:layout_width="wrap_content" but no luck. I also tried the ellipsize, then it shows the ... but i cannot see the other part of the string.by the way my Text are RTL

Answer (score 0):

remove the  `android:maxEms="5"` line in xml file and than try

Comment: if i try this then half my layout gets hidden

Comment: In that case there is something wrong with your style, to which we are not privy. This answer is basically correct. BTW layout_width and layout_height have no effect on the cells in a table.

Comment: @PhilipSheard i have added the stype for it in my main question.please have a look

Comment: @PhilipSheard and this is this link to my previous issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704040/the-screen-moves-to-right-when-textview-data-exceeds-its-size/12704179#comment17152399_12704179

Comment: on the emulator it is showing properly but on the phone when i am testing it is giving me this error

Comment: i think make android:gravity="center" and remove that line which i answered

Comment: no my friend,it does not help. removing that maxEms hides half of my screen.you see tit in the link i posted above in your answer.please help

`<TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerName"
                style="@style/CustomerTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                />`

Comment: Try dropping the layout_weight.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the TextView expand to a second line by setting singleLine attribute to false.

```
<TextView
        android:singleLine="false"
/>
```

Comment: can you please give me the full code for that Textview,becsue i tried this but did not help

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make the textview scrollable so that when the data to display is too much,scrolling will reveal the hidden text.
In the xml file,change LinearLayout to ScrollView layout.